# GET.WORKBOOK function invalid on file reopen (excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have an excel file that uses the GET.WORKBOOK function, which excel told me to save as .xlsm and I did. However, every time I open the file for the day the function suddenly becomes invalid, error message "That function isn't valid".

I can open a new file and the function works.
Moving all the sheets to a new file also solves the problem until I reopen it again.

I have made the folder it lies in to be a trusted location to no avail.

Does anyone have any clues?

Comment: `GET.WORKBOOK` is a Excel 4.0 macro function.  There was a recent change in Excel trust Center where Excel 4.0 macros are disabled by default.  Check in your Trust Center to see if they are disabled.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you sir!!